# Spark PySpark Configuration in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, apache-spark, visual-studio-code, pyspark

I try to configure Apache Spark PySpark in Visual Studio Code.

```
OS : Windows 11
java : 17 LTS
python : Anaconda 2023.03-1-windows
apache spark : spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3
VScode : VSCodeSetup-x64-1.78.2
```

I install the "Spark & Hive Tools" extension pack on VScode and add `Python > Auto Complete: Extra Paths` on settings.json file like below

```
"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
        "C:\\spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3\\python",
        "C:\\spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3\\python\\pyspark",
        "C:\\spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3\\python\\lib\\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip",
        "C:\\spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3\\python\\lib\\pyspark.zip"
    ]
```

I make the Python code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").appName("shit").getOrCreate()

data = [('001','Smith','M',40,'DA',4000),
        ('002','Rose','M',35,'DA',3000),
        ('003','Williams','M',30,'DE',2500),
        ('004','Anne','F',30,'DE',3000),
        ('005','Mary','F',35,'BE',4000),
        ('006','James','M',30,'FE',3500)]

columns = ["cd","name","gender","age","div","salary"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = data, schema = columns)

df.printSchema()
df.show()

spark.stop()
```

But the codes throws the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\VScode workspace\spark_test\pyspark-test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark'
```

So I make the `.env file` on the folder and insert the some paths.

```
SPARK_HOME=C:\spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3
PYTHONPATH=C:\spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3\python;C:\spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3\python\pyspark;C:\spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip;C:\spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\pyspark.zip
```

And I add the following code on the top of Python code:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os

load_dotenv()

print("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-")
print(os.environ.get("PYTHONPATH"))  # It prints the right value
print(os.environ.get("SPARK_HOME"))  # It prints the right value
```

But it throws the same error messages. Do I miss any steps? I can install the pyspark with pip command. But I want to use the imbedded pyspark module of spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3.

Comment: Have you used *Debug* mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself.

First, in [settings] menu, search "Terminal › Integrated › Env: Windows" and click the link [edit in settings.json].
Second, insert the following line.

```
"PYTHONPATH": "C:/spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3/python;C:/spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3/python/pyspark;C:/spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip;C:/spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3/python/lib/pyspark.zip"
```

Then the above python codes work without errors. I hope this will be helpful. Thanks any way.

**== Updated Part**

The file which contains the PYTHONPATH has to be `launch.json`, not `settings.json` file. If you insert the PYTHONPATH line into `settings.json` like what I mentioned above, then it would bring the errors when executing pyspark. The correct PYTHONPATH code is like below in `launch.json`,

```
"version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "python",
            "name": "Launch Python File",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "env": {"PYTHONPATH": "C:/spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3/python;C:/spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3/python/pyspark;C:/spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip;C:/spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3/python/lib/pyspark.zip"}
        },
```